# ошибки Read only asset Packages

Tags: c#, unity3d

вылезли ошибки, пробовал пере-импортировать пакеты все сразу и по отдельности. Удалось исправить с 76 до 34 ошибок. Эти же ни как убрать не могу. не подскажете в чем дело?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы слуаем не до беты обновились?

Comment: Нет я не обновлялся. Я грешу на Google диск автозагрузку и синхронизацию. Он как то при синхронизации удалил файлы мне с проекта. Он обычно удалял временные файлы остающиеся после выхода из unity. У меня вылезло 76 ошибок поискав информацию в интернете, я переимпортировал пакеты и у меня стало 34 ошибки. Помогло только полностью пересобрать проект установить в нем пакеты с нуля. Ладно хоть проект еще пока не большой.